# problems building a maven project with bower on a windows VM

Tags: maven, bower

I have a maven project someone has given me which uses bower.  I am trying to do a basic mvn clean install on a vm I have set up with all the relevant versions.  I have built larger projects on my vm so I don't think there is a network error but I continually get errors along the lines of

```
ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads     git://github.com/angular.bower-angular-mocks.git", exit code of #128 fatal:     unable to connect to github.com: 192.30.252.131]: errno=No such file or     directory
```

I can get to this location from the vm in a browser and run the command in the command prompt so I don't think there is a specific issue with the location.  Also although it breaks at roughly the same point in the build (after bower.bootstrap#3.2.0) it gives different git addresses as failure points each time.

I'm a bit stumped by this.  I've reinstalled bower a few times (npm install -g bower) and there don't seem to be any issues with this.  The only thing I can think of at the moment is that it may be to do with running from a VM (VMware workstation).  I don't want to change versions of software on my main machine though so I thought I'd see if anyone had any ideas before going down this route.

Thanks in advance...

The issue is around the install argument in the POM...

so the relevant entry is

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>bower</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>install</argument>
                </arguments>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

If I remove the argument

```
               <arguments>
                    <argument>install</argument>
                </arguments>
```

then the project builds.  Maybe I should go back and look at this some more.

I'll leave the question open for now though in case anyone has come across it before

bowser.json

```
{
"name": "java-angular-seed",
"version": "0.0.0",
"authors": [
    "Mrs X"
],
"description": "A seed project",
"keywords": [
    "java",
    "maven",
    "angularjs",
    "seed"
],
"license": "Apache 2.0",
"homepage": "http://matador.com",
"private": true,
"ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "src/main/webapp/vendor",
    "test",
    "tests"
],
"dependencies": {
    "angular-loader": "1.5.0-rc.0",
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.0-rc.0",
    "angular-route": "1.5.0-rc.0",
    "angular": "1.5.0-rc.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.2.0"
},
"main": "src/main/webapp/index.html"
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your build file?

Comment: Can you also show us `bower.json` file?

Comment: Do you have more than one ssh key in your .ssh directory?

Comment: I hadn't set one up at all yet on that vm.  I have set one now and it still fails (this time with .../bower-angular.git but it has been switching around a few of these addresses anyway so i don't think that's relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies I have found the answer [elsewhere](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/issues/141)...

git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

"The problem was that bower tried to retrieve packages through git:// protocol, which seems to be blocked at my machine."

Many thanks for your help though.